# Walking on a lattice different step sizes.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I'm studying a particular class of two dimensional piecewise-smooth dynamical systems where there are two switching surfaces $x_1 = 0$ and $x_2=0$. We define switching variables $\lambda_i = H(x_i)$ where $H(x)$ is the Heaviside function. Let $Q_i$ denote the standard $i$-th quadrant of $\mathbb{R}^2$. So,

- In $Q_1$, we have $(\lambda_1, \lambda_2) = (1, 1)$
- In $Q_2$, we have $(\lambda_1, \lambda_2) = (1, 0)$
- In $Q_3$, we have $(\lambda_1, \lambda_2) = (0, 0)$
- In $Q_4$, we have $(\lambda_1, \lambda_2) = (0, 1)$

The discrete time equation can then be written as $$ \vec{\dot{x}} = \lambda_1 \lambda_2 f_1(\vec{x}) + \lambda_1(1-\lambda_2)f_2(\vec{x}) + (1-\lambda_1)(1-\lambda_2) f_3(\vec{x}) + (1-\lambda_1)\lambda_2 f_4(\vec{x})$$
where $\vec{x} = (x_1, x_2)$, $f_i(\vec{x}) = \vec{x} + \vec{v}_i$, $\vec{v}_i = (\alpha_i, \beta_i)$ and
$\alpha_i, \beta_i \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \beta_1, \beta_4 < 0$ and $\alpha_3, \alpha_4, \beta_2, \beta_3 > 0$.

We are interested in the geometry of the attractor that forms around $\vec{x} = (0, 0)$. There is some work related to this from the study of planar piecewise isometries where the invariant region is partitioned into disjoint polygons which are then mapped by the isometries creating a new set of disjoint polygons etc etc.

I was thinking about trying to frame it as a lattice walking problem as there seems to be a lot of existing work in that area.   If we start with some initial condition $\vec{x} \in Q_i$ such that $x_i \notin \mathbb{Z}$ then we can construct a translation of the lattice $\mathbb{Z}^2$ from that initial condition so that no lattice points lie in the sets $\overline{Q_i} \cap \overline{Q_j}$ where $i \neq j$.If the walker is in quadrant $Q_i$ it takes a step on the lattice according to the map $f_i$.

I am interesting in the following questions:

1. What is the fraction of time spent in each quadrant?
2. Is there anything we can say about the geometry of the set of all reachable points starting from a given $(i, j)$.

It's not my area of expertise so it may be a trivial problem and I may not have looked hard enough but if anyone has any resources to suggest, that would be most welcome. Also, I haven't had much training in any really rigorous mathematics so please excuse any issues with presentation etc.

Comment: It appears  from your description that  for $\vec x\in Q_i$, $f_i(\vec  x)= \vec  x+ \vec v_i $ where $\vec v_i =(\alpha_i, \beta_i)$ belongs to quadrant $Q_i$. If so, then I would think that your problem just decomposes quadrant-wise into four non-interacting  linear dynamical systems, $f_i: Q_i\to Q_i$. However, what do you intend to do about edge cases  on axes where two quadrants touch?

Comment: I've added some more detail to the original post, as was too long to put in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a sample plot of a system that (I think) fits the format you described in your third edit of the question. Can you confirm this  version is the type of system you wish to study?

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfajR.png)

P.S. A simpler way to describe your problem is to say that
that  if $x$ is in quadrant $Q_i$, then the piece-wise defined function that describes the updated position of $x$ is $f(x)= x+v_i$ where the displacement vectors $v_i$  are chosen so that each $v_i$ lies in the quadrant opposite that of $Q_i$.
In more detail:

$v_1\in Q_3, v_2\in Q_4, v_3 \in Q_1, v_4\in Q_2$.

Comment: Apologies again, must have been rushing writing up the question, I've changed the original post now so that the alphas and betas are defined so that all the vectors 
 point towards (0,0).